# Request scope bean management in Unit Tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, scope

There have been many questions regarding request scoped management in unit tests and mainly answer is to do not test the scope management, as its a Spring Framework task and it should take care that it works properly. So advice, for example, would be to replace the request scope with thread or prototype type scope in the XML configuration file.

For most of the tests its enough, there are no complaints about not registered "request" scope and tests are running fine. But I do have one case where it is not enough.

Consider following case:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent component;

    public void doSomething(String param) {
        component.doTheThing(param);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:my-scope-tweaks.xml"})
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent component;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        service.doSomething("aaa");

        assertEquals("AAA", component.getTheThing());
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        service.doSomething("bbb");

        assertEquals("BBB", component.getTheThing());
    }

}
```

I want to test MyService, which is request-scoped. `MyComponent` is request scope as well.

## Variant A

If I replace the request scope with `SimpleThreadScope`, then in by both tests I would receive the same instance of `MyService` and `MyComponent`, so for example `test2()` could receive bad results from `MyComponent` as it could internally contain some internal "trash" from previous `test1()`

## Variant B

If I replace request scope with prototype scope - I would get the case where my test methods are receiving different instances of `MyComponent` as `MyService` does - so I cannot perform any assertions on them.

So what I would need is kind of test method-related request scope, where all request-scoped beans remain just during the `test1()` method and then gets destroyed, so within next `test2()` they would be created newly again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but why are you using Spring to manage your test classes in the first place?  That seems like overkill to me.  For unit testing, you shouldn't need a DI container.  Just mock the dependencies and focus on the encapsulated functionality of the Component or Service you're testing.

You won't be able to do that, though, while using field injection.  You'll need to convert to constructor or method injection.

Comment: Its kind of integration test I am doing at the moment. For small unit tests I do not use DI, but in this case - its much bigger and many injections appearing (example is simplified to explain better) - so it would be overkill to redo all work manually what Spring normally does...

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  However, there's still a code smell with how you're injecting the `Component`.  You're wanting Spring to re-inject it again for each test, but that's not going to happen, even with prototype scope (Variant B).  Spring is only going to inject the object once.  To do what you want, you're going to have to actually have a copy of the `Context` and _ask_ Spring each time for the object you need.  Also, can you access the state you need to assert via the `MyService` object, rather than needing a separate copy of `Component`?

Comment: You are right, accessing `MyComponent` via `MyService` with prototype would do the thing for me, so I do not need additionally to `@Autowire` it in my test class.

Comment: @Ryan You can use javax.inject.Provider to get around this. Ex: [link](https://idodevjobs.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/spring-autowired-prototype-scope-using-jsr-330-provider/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to receive a new context for every method in your unit test by annotating the method with `@DirtiesContext`.  This allows you to manipulate beans in the application context for one unit test and not have it affect the others.

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)

Your example annotated with `@DirtiesContext`:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent component;

    public void doSomething(String param) {
        component.doTheThing(param);
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:my-scope-tweaks.xml"})
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Autowired
    private MyComponent component;

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test1() {
        service.doSomething("aaa");

        assertEquals("AAA", component.getTheThing());
    }

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void test2() {
        service.doSomething("bbb");

        assertEquals("BBB", component.getTheThing());
    }

}
```

If all of your test methods within your class require a new context you can also just annotate the class as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:my-scope-tweaks.xml"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyServiceTest {
   //Tests Here...
}
```